# request.responseText receives correct data but JavaScript cannot understand it

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, responsetext

I am new to AJAX and presently learning it from `Head First AJAX`. The problem I am facing is really weird. I developed a simple program that creates a request through JavaScript and then shows the output.

main.js

```
window.onload = initPage;
function initPage() {
    request = createRequest();
    if(request == null) {
        alert("request could not be created");
    }
    else {
        var url = "requestMe.php";
        request.onreadystatechange = showResult;
        request.open("GET", url, true);
        request.send(null);
    }
 }

function showResult() {
    if(request.readyState == 4) {
        if(request.status == 200) {
            if(request.responseText == "okay") {
                alert("A successful request was returned");
            }
            else {
                alert("ALERT : " + request.responseText);
            }
         }
         else {
            alert("Request status received was not correct");
         }
    }
}

//--function to create request objects--
function createRequest(){
   try{
       request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   catch(tryMS){
       try{
           request = new ActiveXObject("Msxm12.XMLHTTP");
       }
       catch(otherMS){
           try{
               request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
           }
           catch(failed){
               request = null;
           }
       }
    }
    return request;
}
```

Now, here is the php script.

requestMe.php

```
<?php
   echo 'okay';
?>
```

This code should give the alert **`A successful request was returned`**

But instead it gives the result **`ALERT : okay`**

The weird thing is this same code was working yesterday for me when I tried it and now it is giving me this result. I tried to create similar programs and they all are showing me this kind of weird behavior. The `responseText` received is correct because it appends **`okay`** after **`ALERT :`**. What wrong am I doing here in the code? Why is it going to the `else` part when the `responseText` received is correct?

Any Help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing add **exit;** after **echo 'okay';**

Issue in your code is after **?>** there is extra space available you can fix it either by removing **?>** or removing extra space after **?>**.

I hope it will fix your issue.

Comment: Exaclty! It was working fine for me too. But it broke down all of all of a sudden. I am using Aptana Studio on Ubuntu 15.04 and I am using FireFox Browser.

Comment: please share your code inside requestMe.php by copying it.

Comment: I checked and double checked it. There is no space or other characters at echo

Comment: <?php
 echo 'okay';
?>

Comment: Can you check it on other browser ? or Other os?

Comment: Ok, so I tried the same on Chrome on Ububtu 15.04 and it had the same problem. But, I tried it on Windows, it worked. Why is  this happening?

Comment: I have edited my answer for it, it will fix your problem, just check the answer

Comment: remove php ending tag **?>**

Comment: This doesn't help either

Comment: send me your both the files I can fix it for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88180/discussion-between-sajib-acharya-and-satender-k).

Answer (score 0):

I personally would do it using [jQuery's Ajax Function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) in the following way:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function()
{
  $.ajax({
    "url": "requestMe.php"  
  }).done(function(data)
  {
    if(data == "okay")
    {
      alert("A successful request was returned");
    } else
    {
      alert("ALERT : " + data);
    }
  }).fail(function()
  {
     alert("Connection Failed");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I haven't tested this Script, but it should in theory work out well.